# What does "auf Habacht" mean?

Tags: meaning, expression

I saw this in a book as a sort of military order, but can’t find it in dictionaries:

> auf Habacht

What does it mean and why isn’t it mentioned?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The direct translation is *[standing at attention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_attention)*.

It is a defined term in a military context.

From [this unofficial source](http://www.dinnendahl.info/formaldienst.htm) on military commands, claiming to quote the [Bundeswehr’s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundeswehr) official *Formaldienstverordnung* manual (the manual itself is not available online from any official source, but this looks trustworthy enough):

> **„Habt acht!“-Stellung**
>
> In dieser Stellung steht der Soldat still.
>   Dieses Stellung wird nur von Ehrenposten, Fackelträgern und Totenwachen eingenommen.
>
> Auf das Kommando „Habt acht!“:
>
> - setzt der Soldat den linken Fuß ungefähr 20 cm nach links.
> - das Gewicht ruht gleichmäßig auf beiden Füßen.
>     Körperhaltung und Blickrichtung bleiben im übrigen wie in    der Grundstellung.
>
> Die Stellung endet mit dem Kommando „Stillgestanden!“.

The term has migrated to the civilian world as well, e.g. in [this Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6ffelhund) about an animal:

> Eine Habachtstellung, die beim Erblicken eines potenziellen Feindes eingenommen wird, beinhaltet eine aufrechte Stellung mit geschlossenem Maul …

or from the [*Stuttgart 21*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuttgart_21) protests, [this headline](http://www.stuttgarter-nachrichten.de/inhalt.stuttgart-21-stuttgarter-polizei-in-habachtstellung.9162f5ee-2307-4c3f-a902-f29231b78a6e.html):

> Stuttgarter Polizei in Habachtstellung

Answer (score 6):

**Habacht** (von *Acht haben*; auch *Habacht-Stellung*) dürfte ein historischer Begriff sein und das Gleiche beschreiben wie heutzutage das **Achtung** bei der Armee.

Beim Befehl *Achtung!* nimmt ein Soldat eine bestimmte Körperhaltung ein und erwartet weitere Befehle. Er befindet sich dann *im Achtung* oder (historisch) *auf Habacht*.

Auch im übertragenen – also zivilen – Sinne werden die Worte *Habacht* oder *Achtung* manchmal gebraucht, um eine vom Befehlston geprägte Beziehung zwischen Vorgesetzem und Untergebenen zu beschreiben.

---

**Habacht** (derived from *Acht haben*, to be aware; also *Habacht-Stellung*, *Habacht* position) is probably a historical term meaning something like today’s **Achtung** at the German army.

On the order *Achtung!*, a soldier takes a specific position and awaits further orders. He can then be described to be *im Achtung* or (historically) *auf Habacht*.

These words are sometimes also used among civilians to describe a relationship that is characterized by a very commanding tone.

Comment: The Austrian Bundesheer still uses "Habt Acht!" as the command. "Habtacht-Stellung" or "Habacht-Stellung" is thus still used in Austria in contemporary times.

Answer (score 3):

*Habacht* includes the words *Achtung haben* meant as *Attention*.

In general it is an expression for attention:

> Hab acht auf deine nächsten Schritte (Watch out on your next steps).

I found an interesting link for [Hab-Acht-Stellung](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Hab-Acht-Stellung.html), this is translated as *position of attention*.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I want to point out that the Austrian army (Bundesheer) still uses “Habt Acht!” as the standard command for standing at attention, apparently equivalent to the German army’s “Achtung!”

The *Habt-Acht-Stellung* (or *Habacht-Stellung*) is characterized by closed legs, body tension, arms placed at the side of the body with loosely closed fists (fingers not stretched out), and looking straight forward.

Typical follow-up commands are marching orders (“Im Gleichschritt Marsch!”), relaxation commands (“Ruht!” for assuming the normal at-ease position, “Parade-Ruht!” for parades, where the general position is kept but the tension is released), or dismissals (“Abtreten!”).

The term *Habacht-Stellung* is used colloquially in Austria to describe someone who has been standing somewhere without much movement for some time (e.g. waiting for something/someone), although its use is diminishing (my parents use it, I don’t).

Answer (score -2):

Auch eine Hose kann "auf halb acht" hängen. Die 8 sollte man eher als ∞ sehen, was wiederum ein Verbildlichung des Hinterns ist. Hängt die Hose also "auf halb acht" kann man den halben Hintern sehen.

Comment: Bei der Frage geht es allerdings um _Habacht_, nicht um _halb acht_. Das ist etwas völlig anderes.

Comment: hm, wie sieht eine Hose wohl aus, wenn sie *Habacht* macht? ;-)